# MySQL select recent message(s) from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, union

I've got the following MySQL table setup: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0bfe/5) [SQL Fiddle #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75a4/1) - What I'm trying to achieve is selecting the most recent message for each individual number. The From and To are always one way or the other, depending on the direction of the message. There could be multiple numbers listed in this table.

Thanks.

**messages_outgoing**

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| ID |             TO |           FROM |                     BODY | SMSSTATUS |                DATE |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 |         Outgoing Message |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:10:00 |
|  2 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 | Another outgoing message |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:20:00 |
|  3 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 |       Final message sent |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|  4 | +4407790000003 | +4407790000001 |         Outgoing Message |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|  5 | +4407790000004 | +4407790000001 |      Another message out |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|  6 | +4407790000005 | +4407790000001 |      Information Message |   pending | 2014-07-21 17:40:00 |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

**messages_incoming**

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+
| ID |             TO |           FROM |               BODY | SMSSTATUS |                DATE |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000000 |  Replying to first |  received | 2014-07-21 17:15:00 |
|  2 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000000 | Replying to second |  received | 2014-07-21 17:25:00 |
|  3 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000005 |       OK, Received |  received | 2014-07-21 17:45:00 |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

**End Results**

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | To             | From           | Body                     | SmsStatus | date                | source   | 
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|  3 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 | Final message sent       | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 | outgoing |
|  4 | +4407790000003 | +4407790000001 | Outgoing Message         | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 | outgoing |
|  5 | +4407790000004 | +4407790000001 | Another message out      | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 | outgoing |
|  3 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000005 | OK, Received             | received  | 2014-07-21 17:45:00 | incoming |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

Conversation between +4407790000000 and +4407790000001 - The latest message would be "Final message sent"

Conversation between +4407790000003 and +4407790000001 - The latest message would be "Outgoing Message"

Conversation between +4407790000004 and +4407790000001 - The latest message would be "Another message out"

Conversation between +4407790000005 and +4407790000001 - The latest message would be "OK, Received"

---

**Possible Solution**

I've come up with the following SQL Query. I honestly think that it's a really bad query, it actually works and returns what I'm after.

```
SELECT `SmsStatus` , `Body` , `all_messages`.`Number` , `all_messages`.`date`
FROM (
    SELECT `SmsStatus` , `Body` , `To` as `Number` , `date` FROM `messages_outgoing`
    UNION
    SELECT `SmsStatus` , `Body` , `From` as `Number` , `date` FROM `messages_incoming`
) AS `messages`
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `messages`.`Number` , MAX(`date`) as `date`
    FROM (
        SELECT `SmsStatus` , `Body` , `To` as `Number` , `date` FROM `messages_outgoing`
        UNION
        SELECT `SmsStatus` , `Body` , `From` as `Number` , `date` FROM `messages_incoming`
    ) AS `messages` GROUP BY `Number`
) AS `all_messages`
ON `all_messages`.`Number` = `messages`.`Number` AND `all_messages`.`date` = `messages`.`date`
```

**Results**

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| SMSSTATUS |                BODY |         NUMBER |                DATE |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|   pending |  Final message sent | +4407790000000 | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|   pending |    Outgoing Message | +4407790000003 | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|   pending | Another message out | +4407790000004 | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 |
|  received |        OK, Received | +4407790000005 | 2014-07-21 17:45:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle - Above Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75a4/5)

Comment: Please add all relevant info also directly into the question. Links can break and your question is then useless.

Comment: Start with the UNION. They're two different tables - but only in your mind! ;-)

Comment: The fiddle and the question seem to be different

Comment: I've updated my original question again, hopefully adding in everything and displaying the expected results.

Comment: This schema layout is flawed... this is why.. you have a from and a to (which first of all are key words so shouldn't be column names) and incoming and outgoing messages so the from and to are inverted for the two tables... you have no way of determining a UNIQUE message.. you need to add a message id to the tables that links each message to eachother in the table.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I believe I have a possible solution (Edited post above) but I have an awful feeling that SQL query is horrible, and possibly going to effect performance.

Comment: as I said before you need to make a unique column to show corresponding messages call it `message_id` ... the query is fairly simple then and will not affect performance and will be scalable... that query is quite a monster and if you are working on a big table it will be slow... but it'll still work

Answer (score 0):

So, given this intermediate result, what should the desired result set look like?

```
SELECT *,'outgoing' source FROM messages_outgoing
UNION
SELECT *,'incoming' FROM messages_incoming;
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | To             | From           | Body                     | SmsStatus | date                | source   | 
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 | Outgoing Message         | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:10:00 | outgoing |
|  2 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 | Another outgoing message | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:20:00 | outgoing |
|  3 | +4407790000000 | +4407790000001 | Final message sent       | pending   | 2014-07-21 17:30:00 | outgoing |
|  1 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000000 | Replying to first        | received  | 2014-07-21 17:15:00 | incoming |
|  2 | +4407790000001 | +4407790000000 | Replying to second       | received  | 2014-07-21 17:25:00 | incoming |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I would be hoping to get the latest message so it would be the last result in your data output, as that's the latest message between the conversation of the To and From.

Comment: My date set is unordered, so I'm not really sure what you mean by 'last'... but perhaps you mean `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: I've updated my original question, with the expected results, with additional numbers to try and explain what I'm after. Thanks again.

Comment: @GeorgeWoodward do you want the result to look like the table you posted? or the four items after the table?

Comment: @JohnRuddell - The four items after the table please.